# What is the ultimate "goal" of two particles in a gravitational field?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, conservation-laws, celestial-mechanics

- What is the ultimate "goal" of two particles in a gravitational field?
- Will the particles eventually occupy the same point at the same time if nothing stops them?
- What stops them from achieving the ultimate "goal"?

Comment: Particles don't have goals. People may have, but it's not always clear what those are.

Comment: Well, the field is generated by something, yes? So they will, attracted by the mass generating it, most often simply impact the body that generates the field.

Comment: @ACuriousMind IMO "impact" implies that something (electromagnetism?) eventually stops them from achieving the ultimate "goal"

Comment: @CuriousOne edited and put quotation marks around the `goal`... could you help me with the wording in this case?

Comment: You could ask how two gravitationally bound particles behave. That's known as the "two body problem" and the solutions are basically elliptical orbits and hyperbolic and parabolic trajectories. I don't think there is a reason to ask about that here. The theory can be found explained many times on the internet.

Comment: @CuriousOne Since when physics is about asking known questions with known answers?

Comment: I merely said that the answer to your question is known and you didn't do much to find it before you came here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate goal of anything in the universe (anything which is around conservative forces) would be to reach a position of lower potential.

So in the case of two particles in a gravitational field, they'd try to have a configuration where they would have the lowest gravitational potential between them, and hence they would move towards each other. (If we assume potential at infinity to be zero!)

The ultimate goal would be for their center of mass to occupy the same place, but that of course is stopped by their repulsion. ( the force which stops two bodies from passing through each other.) This is their least Potential Energy configuration.